# The form contains the following errors: Fingerprint cannot be generated Key type is forbidden. Must be RSA, ECDSA, or ED25519

Tags: gitlab

Hello everyone i have a problem , when i past my '~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub' in my account in gitlab , this is the error i don't know what is the problem

[image]

Comment: What is unclear about "Key type is forbidden. Must be RSA, ECDSA, or ED25519" ?

Comment: What if you 'generate one' ? (and not use the 'existing key') ?

Comment: @Luuk i have generated a new one because it is a different machine

Comment: More info is needed, because you do not tell what you are trying to do, and if generating a new one did solve anything (or did you do that before asking this question?)

Comment: OpenSSH public-key blob (the second field) for ed25519 always begins `AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5` note **four** A's -- could you have mangled or miscopied yours? Also this is borderline offtopic: git is a programming tool, but ssh by itself is not.